# Can not convert object in number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm preparing report. As you can see on screen I have column 'Amount' with objects looks like numbers.

[image: Screen]

I was trying to convert it to number:

[image: Screen2]

NaN values are the one above 999.00 (f.ex 1,000.00). I think that's the issue, Can you please help me convert these data into digits?

Comment: Could you please post your pictures as code? That'll help us, help you. I also don't see `applications_3` in these pictures. Could you post a sample of your dataframe as well?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the Amount values are currency amounts with two decimal places, but no spaces in between each amount. If that's the case, this should split them into individual amounts. I've used one of your sample Amount values:

```
numstr = "1,150.00150.001,150.00100.00400.00800.00"

numlist = []
lastpos = 0

for pos, item in enumerate(numstr):
    if item == ".":
        numlist.append(numstr[lastpos:pos + 3])
        lastpos = pos + 3

print(numlist)
```

The output is a list of the amounts:

```
 ['1,150.00', '150.00', '1,150.00', '100.00', '400.00', '800.00']
```